# Javascript - Showing and closing element issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
<ul class="col-xs-6 pull-right text-right kaup-select">
<li id="kaup-hidden">
    <span id="close-haup" class="haup-close-icon">
    </span>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Garden</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="#">News</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Tools</a>
    </p>
</li>
<li id="kategorie-select">
    <a class="active-crumb haup-ico" href="#">Kategorie</a>
</li>
```

kaup-hidden element is hidden element, and clicking on "kategoie-select" shows this hidden layer.

This is Javascript:

```
$('#kategorie-select').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#kaup-hidden').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#kaup-hidden').show();
    } else {
        $('#kaup-hidden').hide();
    }
});
$('#close-haup').on('click', function () {
    $('#kaup-hidden').hide();
});

// When hidden layer is shown, this code allows to close layer on every element click, but not on layer itself.
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#kaup-hidden");
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

This code works fine, but when i click on "kategorie-select", i want to close "kaup-hidden" if it's visible. But i can't. I think, that changing srtucture of html could do the trick, but i can't change html code, so i need to change Javascript code, but don't have any idea, how.

I hope that question i well written, and i want to thank everybody for help.

Comment: why don't you use toggle function, go with it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/xekxo2v6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code:

```
$('#kategorie-select').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#kaup-hidden').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#kaup-hidden').show();
    } else {
        $('#kaup-hidden').hide();
    }
});
```

with

```
$('#kategorie-select').on('click', function () {
        $('#kaup-hidden').toggle();
});
```

This must work for you. :)

Comment: This code will work only, when i delete : $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $("#kaup-hidden");
        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            container.hide();
        }
    });